# Как в пропсах передать цвет фона при наведении? ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

У меня в стилях --hover-bg по умолчанию стоит синим цветом, а как мне передать в пропсах чтобы при наведении на карточку менялся цвет HEX, который будет указан в пропсе компонента?

сам компонент:

```
import React from 'react'
import './CardLanguage.css'

function CardLanguage({ imageSrc, title, description, hoverText, bg }) {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="icon">
          <img src={imageSrc} alt="icon" />
        </div>
        <strong>{title}</strong>
        <div className="card__body">{description}</div>
        <span>{hoverText}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default CardLanguage
```

стили для него:

```
.card {
    --bg: #f7f7f8;
    --hover-bg: #2a35ff;
    --hover-text: #fff;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--bg);
    padding: 1.5em;
    padding-block: 1.8em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.6, .4, 0, 1), transform .15s ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1em;
}

.card__body {
    color: #464853;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.card> :not(span) {
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.6, .4, 0, 1);
}

.card>strong {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    letter-spacing: -.035em;
}

.card span {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--hover-text);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 100%;
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.6, .4, 0, 1);
}

.card:hover span {
    top: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: var(--hover-bg);
}

.card:hover>div,
.card:hover>strong {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Как вариант - использовать события `mouseover` и `mouseout`, в них менять нужные свойства стилей...